# Making a button write to one JTextField in an Array

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield

I'm working on a TextTwist java implementation and I'm currently working on the GUI. I was wondering if some of you Swing geniuses could help me out. I'm trying to do a GUI where whenever a button is clicked, the text of that button is written into the first empty textField below it. I'm having trouble thinking through how to do it. What I've tried so far makes the first button click fill all the TextFields.

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be great.

```
        private void makeButtonLayout() {
    this.charArray = new char[6];
    ArrayList<Character> charArrayList = new ArrayList<Character>();

        this.charArray = this.randomString.toCharArray();
        for(char tempCharacter : this.charArray){
            charArrayList.add(tempCharacter);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i< 6; i++){

            JButton letterButton = new JButton();
            Character buttonCharacter = charArrayList.get(i);
            charArrayList.remove(i);

            String letterString = buttonCharacter.toString();
            letterButton.setText(letterString);
            this.letterButtonsArray.add(letterButton);
        }

        for (final JButton currentButton : this.letterButtonsArray){
            this.buttonPanel.add(currentButton);    
            currentButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    int i = 0;
                    currentButton.setVisible(false);
                    JTextField temporaryTextField = new JTextField();
                    String temporaryString = currentButton.getText();

                    temporaryTextField.setText(temporaryString);

                    if(textFieldArray.get(i).getText().isEmpty()){
                        textFieldArray.get(i).setText(temporaryString);
                        return;
                    }else{
                        i++;
                        return;
                    }

                }

            });
        }
    }
```

[image: This is a screen shot to help better explain What I'm trying to do]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you method is really strange. You mixed initialization code and execution code. Do it like this:

```
        for (final JButton currentButton : this.letterButtonsArray){
            this.buttonPanel.add(currentButton);    
            currentButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    currentButton.setVisible(false);

                    String temporaryString = currentButton.getText();

                    for(int i = 0; i < textFieldArray.size(); i++)
                      JTextField elem = textFieldArray.get(i);
                      if(elem.getText().equals("")){ // or if you don't want spaces do: elem.getText().trim().equals("");
                          elem.setText(temporaryString);
                          break;
                      }
                    }

                }

            });
        }
```

Comment: I changed my format, but I'm still running into the same issue. When the user clicks the first button, the method puts the text of that button into All empty textfields instead of just the first empty one.

Comment: I adjusted some other code around that method; and by using the ".trim()" variation was able to come to a solution. Thanks so much!